# How to have Bamboo expect a different return code for task?

Tags: asp.net, .net, unit-testing, bamboo

I have a unit test runner task that runs `/c dotnet test --logger trx` through the command line which returns 1 on success, however bamboo fails the task since its expecting 0. My two options here are to have the command return 1 on success somehow, but I figured this approach made more sense. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace unit test runner task with Script task and handle 1 exit code inside script, like

```
if( $LASTEXITCODE -eq 1 ) {
    Write-Output "Command executed successfully"
    # do something 
} else {
    Write-Output "Last command failed"
}
```